# Installing Packages into Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, package

This question has probably been asked a few hundred times and the ones I've seen don't actually help me much.
I need to install matplotlib. I've been trying to install Pip, and then I tried to install Setuptools and then distribute and now I've been told to use setuptools again.
Can anyone give me an easy step-by-step guide to installing packages so I can install MatPlotLib now and then others later.

Thank you.

P.S. Not a clue with this and everyone keeps telling me to type things in and I have no idea where or what.

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 for-matplotlib
```

That should create a virtual environment called for-matplotlib with a for-matplotlib/bin/pip you can use to install matplotlib into for-matplotlib (which uses python3).

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what your OS is.  Pulling off this [webpage](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html), if you are using Ubuntu/Debian, just do:

sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

If you are OSX, check out this [page](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-osx-binaries).